# Custom domain http redirects to https when I don't want it to, why is it doing this?

Tags: google-app-engine

### I am trying to get a custom domain to work with Google App Engine 1.9.7 without SSL

I have done all the [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain);

1. Domain is verified with the proper `TXT` records.
2. Domain is configured in the GAE Cloud Console with the proper subdomain `www`.
3. Application is deployed the `appspot.com` domain and works.

But when I try to got to `http://www.customdomain.com` it immediately redirects to `https://www.customdomain.com` and I get the following error:

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I know that for SSL I need to set up a certificate.

I don't have any of my webapp modules configured to be secure.

I don't want SSL right now, I don't need it right now.

#### I found this little nugget after reading the instructions again and again:

> It's okay for multiple domains and subdomains to point to the same
>   application. You can design your app to treat them all the same or
>   handle each one in a different way.

This is exactly what I want to do but I can't find any information on how to actually do this?

#### How do I get it to stop redirecting to the `http` to `https`?

Comment: Which language are you using, python, java or php? Have you configured your application to be secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was to shut down all instances and remove all versions, then do a fresh deployment from scratch, then I stopped having this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. You say "*I don't have any of my webapp modules configured to be secure.*" If that's the case, sorry, can't help you.

Otherwise the most likely cause for your problem would be: A "secure: always" flag for the respective handler in your app.yaml in the handlers section. Like so:

```
handlers:
- url: /*
  secure: always
```

Remove the line with the "secure: always". Details in the official Google docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element) (table item "secure").

How to run into this problem? I ran into it, because I copied the app.yaml from one of my other apps that didn't need to run on a custom domain, yet needed the SSL always.

For a Django/Python GAE app, by the way, the same problem is caused like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.django.main.app
  secure: always
```

Same answer here: Remove or change the "secure" line. Python version just tested as described. Always works on the appspot.com domain, only without secure flag on a custom domain.

*Just pointing out the above, as other people might run into this problem and come to this threat for help.*

Comment: The provided link is broken.